# Java Server Faces - import image

Tags: java, jsf

I want to import image file into JSF page. I use this code:

```
<div id="greenBand" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-allh"
    style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;">
    <img xmlns="" class="sectionTitle" alt="Download Drivers" border="0"
        style="position:relative; top:-20px; left:9px;"
        src="resources/logo_datacenters.png" />
</div>
```

When I load the JSF page into the web browser I get this error message at the position of the page:

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace declared with prefix img but no
taglibrary exists for that namespace.
```

What tag library am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

whats the purpose of the `xmlns=""` in your img tag ?

remove it...

b.t.w you can use the `<h:graphicImage`...